# How to clone largesets of HTML while also changing attribute values

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex, dom

I have a set of inputs that need to be repeated within my HTML whenever a button is clicked. I currently have a method that will allow me to insert the HTML into the DOM, but I'm afraid this is not a very maintanable solution.

Currently, I have a set of inputs defined as-

```
<div class="input-row">
    <input name="location-0-bol-0-name" id="location-0-bol-0-name" class="form-control">
    <input name="location-0-bol-0-description" id="location-0-bol-0-description" class="form-control">
    <input name="location-0-bol-0-weight" id="location-0-bol-0-weight" class="form-control">
    <input name="location-0-bol-0-type" id="location-0-bol-0-type" class="form-control">
</div>
```

On a button click, I want to copy the  element and all of the inputs nested inside. However, I would need to update name and id attributes of all inputs by incrementing the second numerical value by one. For example, the next set of inputs would be as follows-

```
<div class="input-row">
    <input name="location-0-bol-1-name" id="location-0-bol-1-name" class="form-control">
    <input name="location-0-bol-1-description" id="location-1-bol-0-description" class="form-control">
    <input name="location-0-bol-1-weight" id="location-0-bol-1-weight" class="form-control">
    <input name="location-0-bol-1-type" id="location-0-bol-1-type" class="form-control">
</div>
```

I think I can use the clone() function provided by JQuery, but I'm not sure how I would be able to iterate on all elements and update the attributes properly. Can someone provide some guidance?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

https://jsfiddle.net/cqyg1jwq/

You can clone the row then iterate through the children, creating the id and name for each.

One way, rather than using regex, would be to store the "type" of input in data of each child, so `data-type="name"` for `id="location-0-bol-1-name"`, etc.

```
<button>Clone</button>
<div class="input-row">
    <input name="location-0-bol-1-name" id="location-0-bol-1-name" class="form-control" data-type="name" />
    <input name="location-0-bol-1-description" id="location-1-bol-0-description" class="form-control" data-type="description" />
    <input name="location-0-bol-1-weight" id="location-0-bol-1-weight" class="form-control" data-type="weight" />
    <input name="location-0-bol-1-type" id="location-0-bol-1-type" class="form-control" data-type="type" />
</div>
```

jQuery

```
$('button').on('click', function(){
    var iteration = $('.input-row').length + 1; // how many exist already + 1

    $('.input-row:last').clone().insertAfter('.input-row:last').find('input').each(function(){

        // you can use regex to generate the id and name here if you wanted instead
        // var id=this.is; // then update the numeric value with regex
        // but I prefer to use data

        var type = $(this).data('type');
        var name = 'location-0-bol-' + iteration + '-' + type;
        $(this).attr({
            name: name,
            id: name
        })
    });;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make a template of what you want to insert like so:

```
<div id="input-row-template" style="display: none;">
    <div class="input-row">
        <input name="location-0-bol-__INDX__-name" id="location-0-bol-__INDX__-name" class="form-control">
        <input name="location-0-bol-__INDX__-description" id="location-0-bol-__INDX__-description" class="form-control">
        <input name="location-0-bol-__INDX__-weight" id="location-0-bol-__INDX__-weight" class="form-control">
        <input name="location-0-bol-__INDX__-type" id="location-0-bol-__INDX__-type" class="form-control">
    </div>
</div>
```

Keep a counter of how many rows there are `var counter = 1;`

Then when another instance needs to be added:

```
counter++;
var newRow = $('#input-row-template').html().replace(/__INDX__/g, counter);
```

Then append `newRow` wherever it goes!

Answer (score 0):

[`clone()`](https://api.jquery.com/clone/) provides the iterations needed. It returns a deep copy of the element, which includes child elements as well.

```
var clone = $(".input-row").clone();
```

This should return a clone of the element including all iterables (children) within.

Comment: How would I then change the attributes since JQuery doesn't have built in regex?

Comment: What's wrong with using native JS regex? jQuery is JavaScript, you can use them both.

Comment: Javascript has Regex :D ---> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions